# Installed windows 10 with 32-bit on accident now i can't re-install windows 10 as 64-bit

Tags: windows-10, 32bit-64bit

I recently installed windows 10 and on accident installed 32-bit. Now when I try to re-install windows 10 with 64-bit I receive the error: This version of the program is not compatible with this version of windows. I know i have A 64-bit processor. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to install 64 bit version while you are in side the 32 bit version ?

You CANNOT transfer from 32 bit to 64 bit by running the installer as an upgrade over the 32 bit version.
If you need the 64 bit version, please boot from the installation disc and reinstall the OS from scratch (There’s no upgrade path), 
Also remember to select the 64 bit version in the setup.

If you need more help read this How to geek article

http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/